# UITableView cell selection with progress bar

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a simple UITableView app, which has an SQLITE database (with ~20000 rows), and since every SELECT takes about 3-6 seconds to fetch results so i would like to show the user a progress bar when he touches a cell row, so he knows thats something is happening.

I tried this, but this is not working well, because HUD is appearing only for about 0.1 seconds:

```
 - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading"; 

    return indexPath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you doing in that `SELECT` that's pretty slow - `10,000 objects is considered to be a fairly small size for a data set` [Apple's Core Data Performance Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW1)

Comment: This is the SQL command that i use: SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM table WHERE TYPE = '%@' AND NAME IS NOT NULL AND NAME <> ''"

Comment: Do you have an index on `type`

Comment: @Paul.s thank you, indexes helped a lot in performance!

Answer (score 0):

rather than adding progress bar u can add the a UIActivity indicator in cell accessory. its very easy to create and nice in look-wise.